# OT.Publisher Access Denied: End-user denied permission to hardware devices getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor, opentok

I am trying to create a Live Streaming with Open Tok JS SDK with Capacitor + Ionic + Vue.js but It seems that the code is not supported by iOS.

```
[log] - {"code":1500,"message":"OT.Publisher Access Denied: Permission Denied: End-user denied permission to hardware devices (getUserMedia error: NotAllowedError)","name":"OT_USER_MEDIA_ACCESS_DENIED","stack":"C@capacitor://localhost/js/chunk-90ec66da.9f0ce302.js:37:52873\nx@capacitor://localhost/js/chunk-90ec66da.9f0ce302.js:37:53369\ncapacitor://localhost/js/chunk-90ec66da.9f0ce302.js:37:54452\npromiseReactionJob@[native code]","originalMessage":"The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.","originalName":"NotAllowedError"}
```

[Debug error Screenshot from XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSvrN.png)

Anyone have resolved the bug? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Encryption based security**
The getUserMedia() method is only available in secure contexts. A secure context is one the browser is reasonably confident contains a document which was loaded securely, using HTTPS/TLS, and has limited exposure to insecure contexts. If a document isn't loaded in a secure context, the navigator.mediaDevices property is undefined, making access to getUserMedia() impossible.

Attempting to access getUserMedia() in this situation will result in a TypeError.

**Document source security**
Because of the obvious security concern associated with getUserMedia() if used unexpectedly or without security being carefully managed, it can only be used in secure contexts. There are a number of insecure ways to load a document that might, in turn, attempt to call getUserMedia(). The following are examples of situations in which getUserMedia() is not permitted to be called:

A document loaded into a sandboxed  element cannot call getUserMedia() unless the  has its sandbox attribute set to allow-same-origin.
A document loaded using a data:// or blob:// URL which has no origin (such as when one of these URLs is typed by the user into the address bar) cannot call getUserMedia(). These kinds of URLs loaded from JavaScript code inherit the script's permissions.
Any other situation in which there is no origin, such as when the srcdoc attribute is used to specify the contents of a frame.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#security